# One Flickering LED Bulb On Switch with 4 Bulbs

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

I have a swiych with 4 overhead recessed lights on it. I recently replaced the switch with a [ZOOZ Z-wave dimmer switch](https://www.amazon.com/zooz). It worked great. Nor problems except I had mismatched LED bulbs so they didn't dim evenly. I replaced them all with new [EVEREADY Led Flood Light Bulbs, BR30, 65 Watts Equivalent (10W Led Bulb), 850 Lumen, 2700K Soft White Color, Dimmable, E26 Base Flood Lights for Recessed Cans, Energy Star and UL Certified](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SKLWPYY).

They look great and dim very well with the new switch. BUT one of the bulbs was flickering every 30 seconds to a minute, randomly when at full brightness. It was only one of them so I replaced it with another of the exact same model. It's doing the same thing, which leads me to believe it's related to that particular socket. Interestingly, I did not have a problem with the old LED bulbs. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: I would check the center tab in the socket to make sure the lamp is making solid contact that may cause issues but with the low wattage the only other thing would be the heat sensor , the led should not trip it because of the small wattage but it’s that or a loose connection someplace on that one since you swapped lamps.

Comment: Since you cut-and-pasted the rather lengthy name of the product verbatim off the Amazon page, I went ahead and converted it to a link for you.  I also did a little sleuthing on this "brand of the week" there "Zooz", and I see an ETL listing with a file number, so it "looks legit".   The lights *look* legit but I'm bothered by the fact that it's all Amazon Marketplace 3rd party sellers, Amazon itself does not sell them and Eveready's website does not **even mention** these products. Counterfeit maybe? The prices are "too good"...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm going to try different bulbs and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily an answer as to exactly why the flickering was occurring, but I replaced the "Eveready" bulbs with nearly equivalent Amazon Basic bulbs and there is no flickering. As was suggested above, I also suspect that these bulbs are not genuine Eveready. Either way I'm returning them.